# ZF2 csrf timeout

Tags: zend-framework2, timeout, csrf

I'm trying to increase the timeout of the csrf timeout.
I have change it from in the form configuration like in the documentation from zend https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.element.csrf.html
I have try using a custom validator like here https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/zend-framework-2-utilize-validatormanager-to-work-with-custom-validator-in-zendform/.

The timeout still remains at 5 minutes - the default value.

The question is how can I change this value ?

Comment: Can you share your form code?

Comment: This is from the Form file. The configuration with the custom validator I didn't keep it.
But with this settings the csrf timeout is still 5 minutes.

$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'security',
            'options' => array(
                'csrf_options' => array(
                    'timeout' => 1800
                )
            )
        ));